# MySQL - LEFT JOIN and select rows from table not in another

Tags: mysql, select, join, compare

Ok, so here is an existing query I have that does what I need.

```
SELECT C1.id AS id, C1.title AS title, C1.instructor_id AS instructor_id, 
  C1.description AS description, C1.date AS date, C1.starttime AS starttime, 
  C1.endtime AS endtime, C1.training_id AS training_id, C2.name AS name, 
  C2.id AS instructors_id 
FROM trainings C1 
LEFT JOIN instructors C2 ON C1.instructor_id = C2.id
```

However, I need to add something to it. I have two tables I need to compare in addition to what I have.

Table 'trainings' has a list of training sessions, indexed by 'id'. I also have another table, 'registrations', that holds info about what users registered for what training sessions with 3 columns: 'id' - index, 'user_id' - the ID of the user that registered for a training, and 'course_id' - the ID of the training session.

What I need to do in addition to my existing query, is select ONLY the training sessions that do not have a row in 'registrations' for that user already.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you for who can help. I have tried for hours. The query is just too large for me to keep organized and to think properly about how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT C1.id AS id, C1.title AS title, C1.instructor_id AS instructor_id, 
  C1.description AS description, C1.date AS date, C1.starttime AS starttime, 
  C1.endtime AS endtime, C1.training_id AS training_id, C2.name AS name, 
  C2.id AS instructors_id 
FROM trainings C1 
LEFT JOIN instructors C2 ON C1.instructor_id = C2.id
LEFT JOIN registrations C3 ON < Whatever they're connected on >
WHERE C3.id IS NULL
```

Basicly just `JOIN` that aswell, and filter it through a `WHERE ... IS NULL` since `LEFT JOIN` will return joined table's columns as `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I'm just not understanding. (I've been up all day, so I'm pretty low on brain power. This sites deadline is in the morning and this is the last thing to finish.) Ok, let's say the current logged in users ID is 3. I need to get all rows from the 'trainings' table that do not have a row in the 'registrations' table with '3' in the 'user_id' column. So lets say I had 3 entires in 'trainings', with the IDs of 1, 2, and 3. And lets say in the 'registrations' table I had 2 entires with '3' as the user_id and '1' and '3' as the course_id, I want just the row with the id of '2' returned.

Comment: Hope it all solves out. Just try to JOIN in the `registrations` as you would do if you wanted that data, then add the `WHERE`.